# Change Column Format from numbers to numbers with €

Tags: mysql, sql, format

I have a problem which I still haven't solved after much research. I have a table in which a column is filled with pure numerical values. Now I would like the values in this column to be given a € symbol. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you give sample data and desired output? Also do you want to update the data or you just need to format it while selecting?

Comment: It must be€ So why bother(and it would be bother) store currency symbol when you only have one. If you have multi currency consider storing currency in another column

Comment: Currency is a decoration, it's not part of a value; for an easy life, keep it separate.

Comment: € need only showed in your UI part.  No need to store it in the table.  You can even save the currency unit in a system table if you meet with multiple kind of currency.

Comment: @SeanH yes I only need showed in the UI. But how to save it in a system table ?